# How to set a fixed position at top of div and don't scroll

Tags: css, css-position

I have a div with `overflow-y:auto` as container with two more div's: One for the title and one for the content.

I need to scroll the container but the title has to be static at top of it. Something like this:

```
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-title">
        <h2>My Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried `position:absolute` to `.table-title` but doesn't stuck at top.

Here a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/junihh/faqm85xy/1/

How to set the fixed position of `.table-title` at top of the container?

Thanks to any help or comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only want to make the content area scrollable, not the title. And no fixed position is needed in this case.

```
.table-title {
    background-color: #666;
}
.table-content {
    height: 200px; /*set a height*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```css
.table-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
}
.table-title {
    background-color: #666;
}
.table-content {
    height: 200px; /*set a height*/
    overflow-y: auto;
}
h2, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font: normal 1em/1 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
    line-height: 140%;
}
p:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
    <div class="table-title">
        <h2>My Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="table-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum Minim laborum aute Duis pariatur quis dolore dolor in magna ut dolor est sed cupidatat consequat consequat culpa deserunt commodo deserunt in nulla consequat est est.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/7ngg8f03/

Comment: Scrolling content instead of container is a good point, but I don't see why you would set either element to position fixed.

Comment: Just don't set it to fixed.  Setting the overflow on content instead of container alone seems to answer the question.

Comment: @JamesMontagne good point, totally forgot that, updated answer, thanks for point that out, my mind was stuck in the fixed position thing :)

Comment: Sorry people, maybe I don't make the right example. I really have a container with overflow-y:auto because I have columns into .table-title and .table-content to behave like real tables. Some Explorer show the scroll bar even the don't have rows and I need the columns shrink to new width base on the container and the scroll bar. I write this new demo: jsfiddle.net/junihh/yrck4084

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning is relative to the window of browser.

Instead you probably want `absolute` positioning. `absolute` positioned elements are positioned relative to the the first parent that isn't *statically* positioned.

So by making .table-container `position: relative;` we can make the title position relative to its container.

*Note: absolute position elements require top or bottom **and** left or right to be set. Otherwise you will end up with some unconsistent behaviour across browsers.*

The following CSS should help you out:

```
.table-container {
    position: relative;
    /* Set padding-top to the total height of .table-title to fix the scrollbar */
    padding-top: 67px;

    /* Set width & height to the desirable size. */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.table-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    /* set background color so that it isn't transparent. */
    background-color: white;
}

.table-content {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3k0h9cx/